# cx_Oracle, and Library paths

Tags: python, oracle

Pretty new to all this so I apologize if I butcher my explanation. I am using python scripts on a server at work to pull data from our Oracle database. Problem is whenever I execute the script I get this error:

***Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_52w_forecast_from_oracle.py", line 3, in 
    import cx_Oracle
ImportError: libnnz11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or direct                                             ory***

But if I use:

***export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib***

Before executing the script it runs fine but only for that session. If I log back in again I have to re-set the path. Anything I can do to make this permanent? I'm trying to use Cron as well to automate the script once a week. It was suppose to automate early Monday morning but it didn't run.

EDIT: Just had to add the path to my .bashrc file in the root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was pretty simple. I just had to add it to the .bashrc file in my root directory.